# Sinatra - how do I get the server's domain name

Tags: ruby, sinatra, domain-name

I'm trying to get the domain name in my Sinatra app but as a newbie I really am struggling to figure out how to do this, and I know it must be possible!

`Rack::Request#host_with_port` looks promising, but I don't know how to get this from my app - how do I get stuff from Rack in my Ruby code?

Or is there another way - I'm thinking I don't really want to do this every time a request happens (although it's not too bad), but I thought it'd be better if I could just do it once when the application loads up.

Any hints?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

simply use `request.host` inside your code.

```
get  "/" do
  puts request.host #=> localhost
end
```

Comment: Thanks :) this will definitely work - I'd probably use request.host_with_port, as I need the port number too - I'm still wondering though if I need to do this for every request - is there no way that I can do it once in the application?

Comment: AFAIK, the request object is generated with each request. So, do it once for the whole application is not possible. Although, you can use a before filter to save repeated coding. You can use `before { $Host_with_port = request.host_with_port }` for a before filter.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at:

```
request.env.inspect
```

so you can see all the request environment variables.

I think that you are looking for

```
request.env["SERVER_NAME"]
```

Comment: Cool :) thanks, this helped and let me learn something about request - I didn't realise that the Sinatra Request class inherits from the Rack request - I was wondering where the env attribute came from!

Comment: You can also use request.env["SERVER_PORT"] and request.env["PATH_INFO"] to get the port number and path, or request.env["REQUEST_URI"] for the whole URI.