# How to use get programatically current host from heroku and use it in rspec test?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rspec, sinatra

I'm writting a simple web app (sinatra) thats does [github authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow).

I have to make a create a link with a callback param, somethig like: `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=b5b1a33df1c7b5acccac&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4567/step2callback&scope=public_repo,user,gist,admin:repo_hook,gist`, so that when the uses click on it it will authenticate, authorize my application, then send the user back to my web app.

Since i'm using rspec, I would like to make a code that pass on tests and on production, so I would like to get the current host+port to use it on the code I generate the link, something like:

```
HOST = get_current_host # this is the problem, how to get it?
@authorize_url = @client.authorize_url(@client.client_id,
                                      {
                                      :redirect_uri => "#{HOST}/step2", 
                                      :scope => 'public_repo,user,gist,admin:repo_hook,gist'
                                      })
```

So, my question is *how do I get my current running host on heroku*, so my code would work on test and production?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure different values for [different environments](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Environments)

A simple example given below:

```
# File: test.rb
require 'sinatra'

# Set the values of various host names based on deployment environment
configure(:production) { set :host, "production-host" }
configure(:development) { set :host, "development-host" }
configure(:test) { set :host, "test-host" }

get '/' do
  "Hi #{settings.host}"
end
```

Set `RACK_ENV` environment variable to environment value - `production`, `development`, or `test`

```
>set RACK_ENV=test
```

Run the Sinatra App

```
>ruby test.rb
[2015-12-17 20:20:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-12-17 20:20:46] INFO  ruby 2.1.7 (2015-08-18) [x64-mingw32]
== Sinatra (v1.4.6) has taken the stage on 4567 for test with backup from WEBrick
[2015-12-17 20:20:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11040 port=4567
```

Access the URL:

```
>curl http://localhost:4567
Hi test-host
```

---

If you are using Rack to run your Sinatra app, you could have following as `config.ru`

```
# config.ru
require 'sinatra'
require './test.rb'

configure(:production) { set :host, "production-host" }
configure(:development) { set :host, "development-host" }
configure(:test) { set :host, "test-host" }

run Sinatra::Application
```

In this case, `test.rb` will be simplified like below:

```
# test.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hi #{settings.host}"
end
```

You can specify the environment on command line as shown below:

```
> rackup -E test config.ru
```

---

This answer is inspired from [Sinatra configuring environments on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832060/sinatra-configuring-environments-on-the-fly)

Comment: Hi @WandMaker thanks for the replay, it will help. But it doesn't show how to get the current host from heroku. Let me explain, suppose I create a *new heroku host and and deploy it there*, then I will have to configure the variable again. The log from heroku show us the current host, I was thinking if it there's a way to read the current host the same way the app that create the log does.

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016783/sinatra-how-do-i-get-the-servers-domain-name